# Does V8 engine know how to print generated machine code using Intel syntax?

Tags: assembly, x86, v8, intel-syntax

I'm using D8 shell and the flag `--print-opt-code` to print the code TurboFan generates.

However, the code is printed using AT&T syntax. I'm not familiar with it, but with Intel syntax. I searched in `d8 --help` and didn't find an option for this. Does V8 have an option to print the assembly using Intel syntax? If not, is there a workaround, such as a program that I can run together with D8 to convert the AT&T to Intel syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

V8 supports only one syntax for printing disassembly. It's very close to Intel syntax: destination before source (e.g. `movl eax, 2`), indirect memory addresses like `[eax+ebx*2+1]`.

Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax for reference, I suppose you could say that the one convention V8 takes from AT&T syntax is that operation width is encoded as a suffix of the instruction name, e.g. `movl` is a 4-byte move, `movq` is an 8-byte move, `testb` is a 1-byte test.

Comment: After I asked the question, I noticed the similarities to Intel syntax, but the suffixes confused me... So are you saying that this is a distinct syntax?

Comment: I'd call it "Intel syntax", you can call it whatever you like if you don't agree with that description :-)

Comment: Why do the V8 developers complicate simple things :P